# Two request to get count of rows in database JPA

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have problem with one extra count request, always when I request of count JPA create 2 requests instead of one, and I don't why JPA do this. Is there any possibility that JPA could create just one query about the number of lines? My service and controller place below.

[image: Service]
[image: Controller]
[image: Request]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are calling it twice.

First in the if statement and then in the true branch of the if.
`count()` will give you always a result so there's no need to wrap this in na `Optional`.